# Why is empty string transformed to "(null)"?

Tags: printf, string, c++builder-6

I have following code sample:

```
double t_values[FFT_SIZE];
AnsiString prefix;
double multiplier;
AutoScaleData(t_values, FFT_SIZE, prefix, multiplier);

AnsiString str;
str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix);
```

Pretty simple isn't it?
String *str* is used as description for numeric values displayed in graph. For value say 0.05 V it is much more comprehensive and intuitive to say instead that "voltage is 50 mV". This is ensured through using proper prefix in this case "m". For values range <1; 1000) there is no need to add any prefix. We can for example say "voltage over this element is 50 volts" and this is perfectly understandable. I have problem that library function printf keeps adding string "(null)" when prefix is empty string for example:

"Voltage [(null)V]"

I haven't seen this type of behaviour anytime before when using Microsoft Visual Studio. Can this behaviour be somehow avoided?

Comment: what's wrong with using if(prefix != null) ?

Comment: a simple null check is too complicated compared to the trusting default behaviours of the compilers? get serious.

Comment: `prefix` is not a pointer, so you cannot compare it to `NULL` directly.  `prefix` is a class, so you would be passing `NULL` to the class's `!=` operator, which expects another instance of the class. The class in question is an `AnsiString`, which has constructors for both `int` and `char*`.  Passing a `NULL` to an `AnsiString` constructor will interpret is as an `int`, not a `char*`, so you would effectively be doing a `prefix != "0"` comparison instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer:

```
str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix.c_str());
```

### Detailed Answer:

`AnsiString` contains a single class member, a `char*` pointer named `Data`.  When the string is empty, the `Data` pointer is `NULL`.  The `Data` pointer resides at the starting memory address of the `AnsiString` instance.

When calling `printf()`, its `%s` specifier is expecting you to pass in a `char*` pointer, but you are passing in an `AnsiString` instance instead.  That is effectively the same as passing `printf()` the internal `AnsiString::Data` pointer directly. In other words, this statement:

```
str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix);
```

Is effectively the same as if you had done this instead:

```
str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix.data());
```

That is why `printf()` outputs `"(null)"`. You are passing it a `NULL` pointer to begin with.

The `AnsiString::c_str()` method never returns a `NULL` pointer.  If the string is not empty, `c_str()` returns the `AnsiString::Data` pointer as-is.  Otherwise, it returns a pointer to a static `'\0'` character instead.  Either way, `printf()` does not receive a `NULL` pointer in that situation.  If the string is empty, it receives a pointer to a 0-length null-terminated string, so it outputs a blank string instead of `"(null)"`.

Answer (score 2):

If is very likely that your variable `prefix` is `NULL`. Try this:

```
str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix == NULL ? "" : prefix);
```

Comment: as mentioned by [`Remy Lebeau`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8431261/why-is-empty-string-transformed-to-null#comment10428991_8431261), `prefix == NULL` doesn't work as you'd expect because of `AnsiString`'s overloading, `prefix == NULL` is effectively the same as `prefix == "0"`.. if you want to do it this way, you can do `str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix.IsEmpty() ? "" : prefix);` .. but really, just use `c_str()`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with following construction:

```
str.printf("Voltage [%sV]", prefix.c_str());
```

But i don't understand what is the difference.

Comment: What type is `prefix`? Very good information to have had in the question.

Comment: I'm guessing that `prefix` is of type `std::string`? The `printf`-style functions, when passed `"%s"` expected a `char *` or `char []` type. The `std::string` class do not convert to any of those types, so `printf` will print something else, and it can event crash. The `std::string::c_str()` function returns a `const char *` type string, which can be used by the old-fashioned `printf`-styled functions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Joachim's answer, I've created the following macro (using C):

```
#define ISNULLSTR(x) (x == NULL ? "" : x)
```

And I can use it like:

```
printf("%s", ISNULLSTR(possible_null_text));
```

Hopefully it will help someone reaching here for the same reason.